# How to measure purity of nitrogen gas in a "homemade" way?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, home-experiment, pnictogen

Is there any indicator or a way of measuring purity of nitrogen? The lab-way of doing things is out of my reach and I was thinking about a DIY way. I want to decrease oxidising atmosphere in a container by introducing $\ce{N2}$ but I am not sure about the purity of it.

Comment: There is no easy homemade way. It would help if you say how you would produce it.

Comment: You probably mean $\ce{N_2}$ (typed as `$\ce{N_2}$`: on Chemistry.SE you can use mhchem to render chemical formulas with MathJax), not N3. Also, what is the source of your nitrogen?

Comment: Provide the target $\ce{N2}$ purity and procedure dependent minor components ( $\ce{O2}$, $\ce{CO2}$ etc.). BTW, is applicable replacing $\ce{N2}$ by $\ce{CO2}$, ? As it is easier to generate ( unless its acidobasic activity matters ).

Comment: Since most of the contaminants you might worry about (in particular oxygen) are more reactive than nitrogen, try measuring the amount of gas lost when such reactions occur. Measuring volume is easy and the lost volume will indicate the purity.

Comment: Thanks guys! I am burning the oxygen, creating CO2 and then filtering those gases via Ca(OH)2 aq.

Comment: First, you should have ~1% Ar, in addition to the N2. Second, what purity is *needed*? At home, you could use a diffraction grating, razor slit and camera to make a spectroscope,  but would the Ar confuse results?